# Pig latin function in SML (Operator and Operand error)

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm practicing sml using problems from Ullman(M97) second edition. The problem I am currently working on calls for a piglatin function that takes in a word, explodes it, and checks if the first character is a vowel (a, e, i, o u). If it is a vowel, it implodes the character list back into a string and adds "yay" at the end. If the first character is not a vowel, the function then checks the rest of the characters until it comes across the first vowel. When it does, it places all characters that came before the first vowel at the end of the character list, implodes the new character list back into a string and adds "ay" to it.

**For example:**

```
- pl "able";
val it = "ableyay" : string

- pl "stripe";
val it = "ipestray" : string

fun isVowel (c::cs) = 
    if c = #"a" then true
    else if c = #"e" then true
    else if c = #"i" then true
    else if c = #"o" then true
    else if c = #"u" then true
    else false

fun cycle nil = nil
  | cycle (h :: hs) = hs @ [h]

fun aL (h::hs) =
    if isVowel(h) = true
    then h :: hs
    else aL (cycle (h :: hs))

fun plx (x) =
    if isVowel x = true
    then (implode x) ^ "yay"
    else implode (aL (x)) ^ "ay"

fun pl (x) =  plx (explode x)
```

I have most of the problem done, but I am stuck on why my plx function gives me this:

```
Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]  
operator domain: char list list  
operand:         char list 
in expression: aL x uncaught exception Error
```

and I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the type of `isVowel` is `char list -> bool`.

If you look at `aL`:

```
fun aL (h::hs) = if isVowel(h) = true then h :: hs
                 else aL (cycle (h :: hs));
```

the `isVowel(h)` means that `h` must be a `char list`, and this in turn means that `aL` must have type `char list list -> char list list`, and `implode (aL x)` is an error.

To fix, change `isVowel` to `char -> bool`:

```
fun isVowel c = ...
```

and write `isVowel (hd x)` in `plx`.

Comment: Oh, ok. I see now. Just curious would their be a way to do it without using hd x in the plx function? Just using pattern matching alone.

Answer (score 0):

You may find [Exercism's SML track](https://exercism.io/my/tracks/sml) enjoyable then. There's even a [Pig Latin](https://exercism.io/my/solutions/53bfd0b6bc954803a119dae9d636090a) exercise. :-)

It is quite common to explode, analyse and implode, but it isn't very efficient, and in some cases it isn't easier either. As molbdnilo pointed out, `isVowel` should probably accept a `char` as input instead of a `char list`:

```
fun isVowel c =
    c = #"a" orelse
    c = #"e" orelse
    c = #"i" orelse
    c = #"o" orelse
    c = #"u"
```

For the function that converts a word into pig latin, you can do this entirely with string functions:

```
fun piglatin (word : string) =
    let val firstLetter = String.sub (word, 0)
    in if isVowel firstLetter
       then word ^ "yay"
       else String.extract (word, 1, NONE) ^ str firstLetter ^ "ay"
    end
```

Testing this:

```
- piglatin "pig";
> val it = "igpay" : string

- piglatin "ant";
> val it = "antyay" : string
```

Now, there are corner cases:

- What if the word is the empty `""`?

  ```
  - piglatin "";
  ! Uncaught exception:
  ! Subscript
  ```
- What if the word is the uppercased `"Ant"`?

  ```
  - piglatin "Ant";
  > val it = "ntAay" : string
  ```

Those two problems will need to be addressed to make the string-based `piglatin` function *robust* and *total*.

---

Here is some feedback for the solution you posted:

- Don't write `if P then true else Q`; write `P orelse Q`.
- Don't write `isVowel c = true`; write `isVowel c`.
- `aL` and `plx` aren't the best function names; I'm not sure exactly what they're supposed to except act as *glue* between `pl` and `cycle`, `isVowel`, `explode` and `implode`.